# Chrome Extension | How to detect the way chrome was opened?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm creating an extension that opens a new active tab every time the user opens chrome. It works perfectly, but it also works when chrome is opened by an external link (like from discord, etc.).

Now the tab that is opened by the external link becomes inactive, because the extension opens a new active tab.

How do i detect how chrome is opened? So I can show the new tab when it's opened normally, and do nothing if it's opened by an external link to show the correct tab.

Or is there any other way that would result in the desired result?

Comment: You can use `Process Explorer` to explore what arguments are sent to the main browser process when Chrome was opened: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer Reading those arguments is not supported natively but you can use native messaging host and system APIs to read those arguments

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.